How do I fix the Error BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default
I am trying to implement a schema compare using "@graphql-markdown/diff" or @graphql-inspector
I get the following error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'process' in 'C:\Code\Documentation\developer-portal\node_modules@graphql-tools\load\esm\load-typedefs'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
Along with many polyfill errors
How do I resolve this?
I see a resolution via adjusting the webpack.config but it is not accessible in Docusaurus
